# Move to a new server and keep users logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I want to migrate my app from one server to another and keep the users logged in. I am using Passport for authentication.

I tried to copy the database to the new server as the `auth_access_tokens` are stored in the database.

I tested that by:

1. Login to the old server.
2. Copy the database to the new server.
3. Use the old server token in the new server APIs.

but I got `Unauthenticated`.

Does anyone have a clue how to migrate my app to another server, keeping my users logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the private and public key to the new server, so the encryption token become the same in the old server.